# Probability (Working out the expected value and Variance of the toss of a fair coin)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that a fair coin is toss $50$ times. Every time you bet $5$ dollar on the outcome of the toss. If u guess correctly u get $5$ dollar otherwise u lose the $5$ dollar that u bet with.

(a) What is the expected amount that you can win after $50$ tosses? What is the risk (Variance) that u are taking?

(b)Using Chebyshev's inequality, calculate the probability that the average cash after $50$ games, differs from the mean by less than $18$.

(c) Compare the results obtained in (b) with the results from the central limit theorem

(d)Use the central limit theorem that u will lose more that $75$

What i tried

(a) The expected amount is simply $(50)(5)-(50)(5)=0$. Its the part on the varience that im unsure. I know that Var(x)=E(${x^2}$)-$(E(x))^2$. But couldnt figure out how to find E(${x^2}$) from the information given.

(b)I know the formula for the Chebyshev's inequality, but without   Var(x) i couldnt work out the probability. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to work from first principles (using indicator random variables), or can you use the fact that this the count of winnings has a Binomial Distribution?

Comment: I would use the Binomial Distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find the variance is to recycle results about the binomial distribution.

Let random variable $X$ be the net amount you win in $50$ tosses. Let $Y$ be the number of heads. Then the number of tails is $50-Y$, and therefore
$$X=5Y-5(50-Y)=10Y-250.$$
It follows that $\text{Var}(X)=100\text{Var}(Y)$.

But the variance of the binomial $Y$ is $(50)(1/2)(1/2)$, so $X$ has variance $1250$.

Now everything is ready for the Chebyshev Inequality, and for a normal approximation.